# Can I run Apache2 and Nginx on the same server with only 1 IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx

I recently set up an Ubuntu 12 server (on Rackspace Cloud's next-gen servers). I will be serving about 10 small web apps on this server. Due to how these apps were built, the PHP app need to run on Apache and the Rails apps need to run on Nginx. Rackspace will not allow multiple IPs on a single server. Is it possible to run apache2 and nginx on the same server using the same IP address both on port 80?

The only [information I have found](http://blog.ludovf.net/configure-nginx-to-proxy-virtual-hosts-to-apache/) involves using nginx to proxy requests to apache for the apache domains. The proxy information I have found mentions only static pages server directly by nginx.

How can I set up my Ubuntu server to run apache2 and nginx on the same server with only 1 IP address?

Comment: What Rails server are you using (passenger, thin, mongrel, etc.)? There's no reason you have to use it in nginx instead of apache, or vice-versa.

Comment: I'm using Thin as the rails server.

Comment: Then you could just have Apache proxy to thin, or have nginx run PHP. No need to have both Apache and nginx.

Comment: I think you can configure both of then on same IP but different ports.

Comment: @ArashMousavi I will need them both on port 80

Comment: @MichaelHampton The problem with running PHP through nginx is that the apps have specific .htaccess criteria that requires apache. For instance, there are 2 wordpress apps/sites and 4 CakePHP apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the same port? No.

However, both Apache and Nginx had reverse proxy support. So run one of them on port 80 and the other on another port. Then configure the one on port 80 to reverse proxy requests matching a particular format (one possibility is subdirectories) to the other.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain or provide a guide on how to set up nginx to proxy requests across to apache? As noted, the information I found doesn't explain how to do this using both dynamic rails apps on nginx and php apps on apache: http://blog.ludovf.net/configure-nginx-to-proxy-virtual-hosts-to-apache/

Comment: That article you linked to is exactly what you need. Configure nginx how you normally would for rails and add a location entry for some subpath to proxy to apache.

Comment: I would suggest using nginx as a reverse proxy instead of apache because nginx is light weight. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html for configuring nginx as reverse proxy

Comment: Thanks. I finally got both servers working using nginx as the reverse proxy and apache2 sitting behind it on 127.0.0.1. I had a few problems with configuration, but this page was a great start: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.04